# Show Alert message in MVC website on home page when opened for the first time in a browser

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, local-storage

I want to show a alert message on the home page of a website, only when the website is accessed for the first time in a browser. If a new tab is opened and site is accessed again, the alert message should not be displayed. But if I close the browser and open it again and then I access this site the alert message should be displayed. How should I achieve this in MVC project?
If I will be using "Sessions", I guess the alert message will be displayed in every tab I access the website. And if I use "LocalStorage", the alert message won't be displayed even if I close the browser and open it again. Kindly suggest me the best way to achieve this or any alternative.

Comment: you should use static flag type global variable and set it first time and check and after alert display change flag value

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is HTML5 SessionStorage API. SessionStorage variables live only as long as the tab is open, as opposed to LocalStorage, which lives until manually cleared on the browser i.e. it has no expiration date.

You can find more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage, the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated, which differs from how session cookies work.

Comment: I want variable to live as long as browser is open and not for just a tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, create a hidden field on your _Layout.cshtml:

```
 <input id="inputAnnounce" type="hidden" value=@Model.entUserSession.blIsAnnounce name="Announcement"/>
```

Then on your Javascript section, you can check the value if it's true or not:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      if (inputAnnounce == "True") {
           //Do your alert logic here 
        }
    });
```

Then on your Model entity, add additional property on your UserSession model, which on my case is entUserSession:

```
public static bool blIsAnnounce
    {
        get
        {
           return _blIsAnnounce;
        }
        set { _blIsAnnounce = value; }
    }
```

Make sure when someone close your dialog box, call a function on your controller to make the value false so that it will not appear again unless they log-out and login:

```
public ActionResult fncCloseAnnouncement()
    {
        Model.entUserSession.blIsAnnounce = false;
        return null;
    }
```